# Activate materalize css form on same page?

Tags: php, css, forms, materialize, contacts

I am builing a site using materialize css html, I would like to activate this form so that it sends information but stays on the same page with a success message.

For some reason it redirects to a different page and gives me the following php syntax error message.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Contact Form Submit() in 26 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in on line 26

Html

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="contact.php" class="contact-form" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="card-panel grey lighten-4">
    <h5>Please fill out this form</h5>
    <div class="input-field">
        <input  id="name" name="name" type="text" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
        <label for="name">Full Name</label>
        <span class="helper-text" data-error="Please enter name" data-success=""></span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <input id="email" type="text" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <span class="helper-text" data-error="Please enter email" data-success=""></span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <input id="phone" type="text" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
        <span class="helper-text" data-error="Please enter phone number" data-success=""></span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        <label for="textarea1">Message</label>
    </div>
    <!--<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn blue white-text waves-effect waves-light">-->
    <button class="btn blue waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
    </button>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php


$prenom = !empty($_POST['first_name']) ? $_POST['first_name'] : NULL;
$nom = !empty($_POST['last_name']) ? $_POST['last_name'] : NULL;
$from = !empty($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : NULL;
$msg = !empty($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : NULL;
$tel = !empty($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : NULL;
$headers = 'From: WEBSITE E-MAIL';
//  echo "$msg" . "$nom" . "$from";

if(empty($prenom) || empty($nom) || empty($from) || empty($msg)) 
{

}
elseif(mail('EMAIL ADRESS', "Commande Amarrex de $prenom $nom", "$prenom $nom a ecrit : $msg \n\n\n E-mail de contact : $from\n\n Telephone : $tel", "$headers"))
{
     echo 'Mail sent.';
}
else
{
    echo 'mail not sent, unexpected error';
}

$to = 'test@localhost';
$subject = 'Contact Form Submit'
($to,$subject,$message){
    $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!"

}


?>
```

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow,

Please include the exact error message produced by PHP. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$subject = 'Contact Form Submit'
($to,$subject,$message){
```

Those two line are bugged.

You are missing a semicolon at the end of the first one, so

```
$subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
```

and the other one makes no sense at all?
I would guess you meant

```
if(mail($to,$subject,$message)) {
```

Comment: Thanks I'm trying to get information from the form.

Comment: Sigh still didn't work, not sure what I'm doing wrong.